# How can I load specific number of items in Django and then load more items after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views

I added some products with using this function in my views:

```
def All( request  ):
    p=product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':p})
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<div class="grid">  
  
         {%for p in p%} 
                <div class='card'>
                    <img src="{{p.image}}"></img>
                    <p id="id">{{p.description}}</p>
                    <a href="{{p.buy}}" target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
                        <button ><span class="price"> ${{p.price}}</span> buy</button>
                    </a>    




                </div>

         {%endfor%}
```

But I do not know what should I do to be able to limit the products, for example I want to have 10 products after the page is loaded and then after scrolling I want 10 more products to appear.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this help? https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pagination
you can read about it here in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/)